# How can I set a WCF service base address port number dynamically in app.config?

Tags: c#, wcf, port, app-config, nettcpbinding

I currently have a `netTcpBinding` endpoint that is listening on port 8000.

I have configured the base address in the `app.config` file like so

`net.tcp://*:8000/TestProject/Service`

This works as expected and the service listens on port 8000.

My issue is that this service will be deployed on third-party machines and I am concerned about port collision (and experiencing `System.Net.SocketException` when trying to open a port that is already in use by another application).

I *can* handle the exception and use `IPGlobalProperties` to find an available port in code to recreate the base address using a free port but I was hoping there was a way to instruct WCF to use a dynamic port in the `app.config` setting.

The client connections do not need to know a predefined port number as they use WS-Discovery to find the server endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this in your app.config.

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="Port" value="8000" />
</appSettings>
```

And read it out in the code

```
string port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"];
```

After you read the port in you have to create the url.